# Where i am going wrong in finding normal to curve?

Tags: derivatives, analytic-geometry, applications

The question is

> Find the perpendicular distance between the normal to the curve $$x=a\cos t+at\sin t, y=a\sin t-at\cos t$$ and the origin.

Equation is given in parameterized form.

**My attempt**

finding slope of tangent to the curve at point $\theta$ 
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}|t=\theta;\implies tant| t=\theta$$
therefore slope at $\theta$ is equal to $\tan\theta$ slope of normal :$$\implies m=-\cot \theta$$

finding equation of normal at point $(acos\theta+a\theta sin\theta, asin\theta-a\theta cos\theta)$ by using $y-y_1 =m(x-x_1)$

$$y-(asin\theta -a\theta cos\theta)=-cot\theta(x-(acos\theta+a\theta cos\theta))$$ on finding distance of this line from origin we get the answer $a$ but the answer in my book is $a/2$

can anyone please tell me, why i am going wrong?

Comment: Are you using $\;\alpha\;$ as variable? I find this rather confusing: why?? Or maybe $\,\theta\,$...but then $\;x\;$ is a constant function...? It'd be a good idea, I think, to use $\;t\;$ for the variable.

Comment: @Joanpemo $\alpha$ is a variable but theta is some point on that curve

Comment: Thank you, yet I still can't parse $\;x=a\cos\alpha+a\alpha\sin\theta\;$ . Is this a trigonometric function of alpha *plus* a linear function? And to add to the confusion, in your question's body you use $\;d\theta\;$ ....so $\;\theta\;$ is a variable after all?! Honestly, think seriously of rechecking the way you wrote your question. I find it pretty confusing, though perhaps it is only me...

Comment: is my question clear now @Joanpemo

Comment: Thank you. No, not so much for me, still...but don't mind me: perhaps someone else can take a look at this. I find it pretty hard, and even annoying, trying to tell apart $\;a\;$ from $\;\alpha\;$ . Too much work for me.

Answer (score 3):

The normal simplifies to become $$y\sin t+x\cos t-a=0$$ 
Therefore the distance is $a$ and not $\frac a2$, so you are right and the book is wrong.